# How do you kill the Turtle boss in the fire area?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

This boss went through 3 bottles with fairies. I have no idea what I'm supposed to be doing.

1. How do you avoid his attack where he's under the grate, shooting up a constant stream of fire, moving towards you wherever you run?
2. How do you avoid his attack after he gets on top of the grate, where he spins around and moves all over the level? Is this just purely luck based?
3. How do you avoid his attack where the entire arena seems to explode or something I don't even know just that it wrecked me.
4. How many times do you have to hit him? I hit him in the head with what felt like 30 icicles and at least as many sword swings, and he just wouldn't go down.

What's the strategy for this guy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a crapload of trouble with this guy. First of all, take fairies (which you've been doing).

In order:

1. I tended to weave in an almost clover leaf pattern around the edges of the level, going around the outside of the areas with pots. As long as you avoid the fire that comes through  the floor, that should work.
   [image]
2. For this, I hid in the corners, facing out with my shield. Make sure you are RIGHT IN THE CORNER. You should be safe there.
3. This one is hard to see, but he spits a dark red cloud first - this shows where the fire will be. There will be a safe area outside it, so just run like snot. You should be able to make it out.
4. He lasts for just about forever. When he gets onto the grate, I counted how far along I was by the number of times he would stretch his head out at me (he does it more times consecutively as he gets closer to death, from 1-4). When he starts flashing red (kinda like bombs do before they explode), you know he's close to dead.

I found it was a lot easier to just spam the ice rod on him instead of trying to get in with the sword. It seemed more effective to me.

Comment: On my second attempt, I ended with full health and fairies. I was able to avoid just about everything (although I made a mistake at the beginning I was able to heal using the potskulls). I used the bow for damage, to avoid getting too close.

Comment: @StrixVaria Awesome! I didn't have the bow, so I never even thought of it as a choice :P